# Como seleccionar un elemento en especifico del DOM con jquery sin id o la clase

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

tengo un sitio web y quisiera seleccionar un elemento en especifico del dom pero con el inconveniente que no se puede seleccionar por medio de la clase o el id ya que se genera automáticamente o cambia de vez en cuando y el script que quiero hacer con jquery debe ser genérico.

Intente con

```
jQuery( ".variations select:nth-last-child(2)" ).append( "<span> - 2nd to last!</span>" );
```

Pero no me funcionó.

Aqui en la imagen muestro que elemento quiero seleccionar.

[image: imagen de como seleccionar un elemento del dom]

Comment: Por que no usas el `name` del `select` si es fijo? además la idea de hacer un `append(span)` no deberia funcionar dentro de un `select` (si un `append(option)`)

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, el append es solo de prueba, tengo pensado hacer otra cosa. Solo quiero seleccionar el segundo select que esta dentro de la clase variations

Comment: Necesitaríamos saber varias cosas para poder ayudarte. ¿Se podría seleccionar por `name`? ¿Tal vez por su `data-attribute_name`? En caso negativo. ¿El `select` a seleccionar está siempre en la segunda fila dentro de la segunda celda de tu tabla?

Comment: Hola, si. Siempre esta en la segunda fila dentro de la celda de mi tabla.
Lo que pasa es que por cada producto varia el select, es decir, para ese producto se generan esos atributos para otro producto se generan otros atributos y así sucesivamente.

Entonces lo que quiero es poder siempre seleccionar el segundo select de esa tabla independientemente de los atributos de ese select.

Answer (score 5):

Hola ya solucioné (Gracias a un amigo), el problema que tenia estaba en que técnicamente los select no son hermanos, la solución esta en colocar el nth child al tr y luego del tr puse el select.

```
jQuery( ".variations tr:nth-child(2) select" ).append( "<span> - 2nd to last!</span>" );
```

Gracias a todos por responder. :)